# How to get active directory users those are modified in certain interval?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have a situation where I need to get the list of users those are created/updated in active directory in last few hours (e.g. 4 hours).

To be very precised, i want the users those email or name has been updated. not other properties.

The solution required is in c#. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The `whenChanged` attribute has the date the account was last changed, so you can search against that. Your LDAP query would look something like this:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(whenChanged>=20190213000000.0Z))
```

The date format you need to use is: `YYYY MM DD HH mm ss.s Z` (but with no spaces). The `Z` indicates that it's UTC time. If you prefer to use a time zone, you can replace the Z with the time zone offset. For example, to find users modified after 9:00 AM today in my time zone (Eastern), I'd use this:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(whenChanged>=20190213090000.0-0500))
```

Here is a quick example of how to use this:

```
var search = new DirectorySearcher(new DirectoryEntry()) {
    PageSize = 1000, //if you omit this, you'll never get any more than 1000 results
    Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(whenChanged>=20190213090000.0-0500))"
};

//add whatever properties you want to use here
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");

using (var results = search.FindAll()) {
    foreach (SearchResult result in results) {
        if (result.Properties.Contains("mail")) {
            var mail = (string) result.Properties["mail"][0];
            //do something with this information
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gabriel for the suggestion, by this i am getting all the record those have been changed. i want only those records where name or email has been changed or a new account is created. Any suggestion for that?

Comment: Gabriel, whenChanged attribute is not replicated between domain controllers. How about using dirsybc control, which detects changes for whenCreated, name or email attributes with user/inetorgperson filter?

Comment: @ShaikhFarooque You can't differentiate between changes to specific attributes. AD doesn't track that. Even just a user logging in will update `whenChanged`. If you want to find recently-created objects, use `whenCreated`.

Comment: @oldovets It's true that `whenChanged` is not replicated, but it does get updated when other changes are replicated, so the times on each DC will be pretty close. I've never used DirSync, so I can't comment on it.

Comment: Hm, interesting. Always thought that whenChanged shows the last object modification time on that DC. For example, when you log on to the DC, lastLogon attribute is modified, so whenChanged is modified as well. Ok, so here is an example on how to use DirSync: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysynchronization?view=netframework-4.7.2. You can specify only attributes, you want to be notified when they are changed. Also a filter can be provided to track only users

Comment: Just checked whenChanged. Yeah, it's modified when the replication occurs, which seems logical. I've learnt today. Thanks, Gabriel